# Javascript code make Internet Explorer not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I have a Javascript code that I use to put ellipsis on a shop grid for titles and descriptions. It works as it should in Chrome, Mozilla and Safari. However, sometimes in Internet Explorer (tested on 11.0.22), this certain page stop responding on loading for several seconds and most of the times, I have a not responding on the window. If I remove this part of the code, then the problem isn't there.

Do something on my code affect the performance and what should I change to solve it?

**Javascript code:**

```
function dotify(element) {
    var limit = element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight;
    var dots = document.createElement('span');
    if (element['data-inner'])
        element.innerHTML = element['data-inner'];
    else
        element['data-inner'] = element.innerHTML;
    dots.appendChild(document.createTextNode('...'));
    element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    element.appendChild(dots);
    while (dots.offsetTop + dots.offsetHeight > limit) {
        dots.previousSibling.data = dots.previousSibling.data
            .replace(/\W*\w+\W*$/, '')
    }
}


jQuery(".product-description").each(function() {
    if (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight ) {
        dotify(this);
    }
});

jQuery(".product-title-grid").each(function() {
    if (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight ) {
        dotify(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well there is a lot of looping and changing of content in the DOM. That can lead to slow performance in IE>

Comment: I'd say it's the while loop running furiously while the values of `dot.offsetTop` and `dot.offsetHeight` are lagging behind any changes made in the while loop that effect `dots.offsetTop` and `dots.offsetHeight`

Comment: This can be also be done with CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow). Offhand, I don't see anything happening here that you wouldn't get from just using the CSS.

Comment: @ebenpack Correct me if I am wrong, but this CSS is not cross-platform and it doesn't work on IE.

Comment: There's a browser compatibility section on the page I linked, and more information here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow Support looks very good to me.

Now, depending on your existing markup/styling, this may or may not work for you, but I'd say it's worth a try anyway.

Comment: @ebenpack Probably doesn't work for multi-lines https://jsfiddle.net/xg6yptef/1/